# getting an error if mapping is not there with EF core code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

Hi all i have model `sections` like this below

```
public class Sections
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public  Requests Requests { get; set; }
}
```

the structure of the data for sections model like this below

```
 sectionId      Name      description
      1         code1       code 1
      2         code2       code 2
```

i have one more model `Requests` and the model looks like this below

```
public class Requests
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string  Description { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public  Sections sections { get; set; }
}
```

and  the structure of sample data for Requests model like this below

```
RequestId   Description   SectionId 
    1          test1         1
    2          test2         1
    3          test1         2
    4          test2         2
```

with this structure of model data i am mapping these two models below

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Requests>()
     .HasOne(a => a.sections)
     .WithOne(o => o.Requests); //not sure if this is correct way to map these two models with one-to-many mapping as listed in requests model
```

is that above mentioned mapping is correct way to achieve the same and  I am using Entity framework core code first approach.

if i don't use above mapping i am getting this error:

> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between `Requests.sections` and `Sections.Requests`.

Could any one please let me know if there is any other way to map those two models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample data for Requests shows that the relationship between `Section` and `Request` is one-to-**many** (for instance, there are 2 requests with `SectionId == 1`).

So the current reference navigation property

```
public Requests Requests { get; set; }
```

which implies one-to-**one** should become collection navigation property

```
public ICollection<Requests> Requests { get; set; }
```

Now you can use `HasOne` + `WithMany` or `HasMany` + `WithOne` to configure the relationship. But that most likely won't be necessary because usually EF Core can conventionally determine the one-to-many relationships.

So while not strongly mandatory, it would be better to use singular names for entities and reference navigation properties, and plural names for collection navigation properties:

```
public class Section
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string  Description { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

This way you will be following EF Core conventions and in most of the cases won't need data annotations / fluent configuration.

**Reference:** [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: Many thanks for detailed explanation, for these two model mappings i do not need write any mappings externally under db context right

Comment: Right. Even if you don't use migrations, you can always `Add-Migration` to create temporary migration and see (inside `Up` method) how EF Core maps your entity model to database (and  `Remove-Migration` when you are done).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<sections>()
 .HasOne(a => a.Requests)
```

Comment: I am looking kind of one to many relationship.. there will be more sections in requests table like i shown in the requests table..